# RewriteBase with WAMP not working (vhost)

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, wamp

I have a problem, let me explain.

Rewrite_module is enabled on WAMP

My host is mapped:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost 
127.0.0.1 mydomain.com
```

My vhost declared on WAMP:

```
<VirtualHost *: 80>
  ServerAdmin contact@mydomain.com 
  DocumentRoot "E:/wamp/www/subfolder/" 
  ServerName mydomain.com
  ErrorLog "logs/mydomain.com.log" 
  CustomLog "logs/mydomain.com.log" common 
  <Directory "E:/wamp/www/subfolder /"> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
    AllowOverride All 
    Order allow, deny 
    Allow from all
  </ Directory> 
</ VirtualHost>
```

For now, no problem, mydomain.com arrives on E:/wamp/www/subfolder/

My projects are in sub folders such as E:/wamp/www/subfolder/my-project/

I have a htaccess with:

```
<Mod_rewrite.c IfModule> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /my-project/ 
RewriteRule ^index\php$ - [L] 
RewriteRule ^assets/css/(.*) /my-project/content/themes/assets/css/ $ 1 [QSA, L] [QSA, L] 
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! F 
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -d 
RewriteRule. /my-project/index.php [L] 
</ IfModule>
```

My problem comes here. If I go on mydomain.com/my-project/ it comes to the site with no problem, but the css (for example) are not loaded, because the link is:

mydomain.com/content/themes/assets/css/ 
It should have:

mydomain.com/my-project/content/themes/assets/css/

I think the RewriteBase not working and I do not know why.

Thank you very much and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the point of a Virtual Host.

You should create a Virtual Host for EACH of your projects so something  like this

```
<VirtualHost *: 80>
  ServerAdmin contact@mydomain.com 
  DocumentRoot "E:/wamp/www/subfolder/project1" 
  ServerName mydomain1.com
  ErrorLog "logs/mydomain.com.log" 
  CustomLog "logs/mydomain.com.log" common 
  <Directory "E:/wamp/www/subfolder/project1"> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
    AllowOverride All 
    Order allow, deny 
    Allow from all
  </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *: 80>
  ServerAdmin contact@mydomain.com 
  DocumentRoot "E:/wamp/www/subfolder/project2" 
  ServerName mydomain2.com
  ErrorLog "logs/mydomain.com.log" 
  CustomLog "logs/mydomain.com.log" common 
  <Directory "E:/wamp/www/subfolder/project2"> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
    AllowOverride All 
    Order allow, deny 
    Allow from all
  </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

This makes each project look and react like it was a single website on its own unique Apache instance and makes moving your projects to live servers more reliable.

You also do not need a `.htaccess` now unless this one project actually requires it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but my problem is right here. I must keep mydomain.com/my-project format because I have to use an external database (located on a server shared dev), which has tree-mydomain.com/my project. Again, thank you.